# Bootstrap4 body doesn't show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.navbar-btn {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.navbar-btn:hover {
    color: skyblue;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.dropdown-item {
    color: white;
}
.dropdown-item:hover {
    color: skyblue;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <!-- Do this better somehow -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown pull-right">
      <button class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="btnSettings" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right bg-inverse" aria-labelledby="btnSettings">
        <!--<button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Login</button>-->
        <!-- fa-address-card -->
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Profile</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Logout</button>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <h6 class="dropdown-header">Global Config</h6>
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Lang</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-window-maximize fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Theme</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div style="color:black;">Hello World!</div>
```

I have a bootstrap 4 top nav and my body won't show, the **hello world** at the end. What's going on? I don't see a reason for it to not show.

Is this a css issue or an html issue? My code compiles properly everywhere i try in online editors, so it doesn't look like an environment issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hidden behind `nav` so just add a `margin-top` so you can see it now:

```
.hello{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Solution 1: (add margin-top):

```css
.navbar-btn {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.navbar-btn:hover {
    color: skyblue;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.dropdown-item {
    color: white;
}
.dropdown-item:hover {
    color: skyblue;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.hello{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <!-- Do this better somehow -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown pull-right">
      <button class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="btnSettings" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right bg-inverse" aria-labelledby="btnSettings">
        <!--<button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Login</button>-->
        <!-- fa-address-card -->
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Profile</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Logout</button>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <h6 class="dropdown-header">Global Config</h6>
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Lang</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-window-maximize fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Theme</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="hello">Hello World!</div>
```

Solution 2: (remove `fixed-top` and use `sticky-top`) since set position fixed will shift the content up:

```css
.navbar-btn {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.navbar-btn:hover {
    color: skyblue;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.dropdown-item {
    color: white;
}
.dropdown-item:hover {
    color: skyblue;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <!-- Do this better somehow -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown pull-right">
      <button class="btn navbar-btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="btnSettings" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right bg-inverse" aria-labelledby="btnSettings">
        <!--<button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Login</button>-->
        <!-- fa-address-card -->
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Profile</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Logout</button>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <h6 class="dropdown-header">Global Config</h6>
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Lang</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-window-maximize fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Theme</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="hello">Hello World!</div>
<pre>
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
71
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
7</pre>
```

Comment: wait, is that common? I didn't see that in the bootstrap documentation or did i mess up?

Comment: @JordanGS because `fixed-top` it is position: fixed, which are out of the normal flow, so your content shift up

Comment: can i ask you one more question? Rather than making a new one. Are you able to get the bootstrap 4 modal to show? I'm directly copy pasting the code and nothing pops up when i press the button. P.S Changed it to sticky top. I'll select yours as the answer when it lets me. Thanks again :)

Comment: @JordanGS could be related to the reference?  haven't done much bootstrap4, thanks!

Comment: @JordanGS Oh, I found a mistake at their site, the code is wrong, this link https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#live-demo. The `data-target="#exampleModal"` does not match `id="myModal"` if you match both like ``id="exampleModal"`` it will work. https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/ktpfcLcv/